# What is the best architecture to expose a single socket connection to multiple activities or fragments?

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, global-variables

I'm responsible for replacing a few screens in an old Java Swing
desktop application with an Android native one and would really
appreciate some advice on the best way to architect the Android app.

The old app has a really light weight sockets based client-server architecture with
only small amounts of data being transferred over the Internet.
The back-end server application handles all validation
and business logic. All the screen information that is
needed by the Java application to paint the Swing widgets
dynamically is sent over the socket connection. In the
old app hundreds of different screens are created this way.

In the old Java app a reference to the socket class is passed to other classes and then
one of socket class methods is called. it returns a string buffer
that is parsed and and used by other classes in the application to
paint the Swing screens at runtime.

The Android app will be much simpler with even less data going back
and forth (a few kb or less). Only a few activities and/or
fragments will be required and the views and widgets won't be
dynamically created. But the text values showing in textviews on
these screens still needs to be sent over a socket connection from the
server and user input from button clicks sent back.

So what is the best architecture for implementing the socket server in
the Android app so that a single socket connection will be accessible
and in scope for all of the different activities or fragments in the
Android application?  Is there a way to make the same Android socket object visible globally or do I need a caching mechanism or a service or is there something simpler?

Thanks

Comment: The fact that this happens to be using a durable socket connection does not really matter much. You could be using REST or GraphQL or websockets or gRPC or a variety of other communications protocols and have the same issues. Modern Android architectures tend to use singleton repository objects as the bridge between data sources (servers, local databases, etc.) and UI concerns (viewmodels, activities/fragments). See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), for example.

Comment: See also [this Google I|O 2019 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZBg5DIzNww) and up-to-date books on Android app development.

Comment: @CommonsWare A lot to think about! Would KOIN and DI would be a solution? The sockets logic could go into a module and be accessible to provide information as required to my activities or fragments. Do you think this approach would work?

Comment: Dependency inversion is a fairly popular technique for setting up and managing singletons like a repository. Koin is a popular DI framework for Kotlin, and it is the one that I prefer to use for small and medium-sized projects.